# limit of the form $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{3^{3n}\cdot \left(\binom{2n}{n}\right)^2}{\binom{3n}{n}\cdot \binom{6n}{3n}}$

Tags: limits

Finding limit of the form  $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{3^{3n}\cdot \left(\binom{2n}{n}\right)^2}{\binom{3n}{n}\cdot \binom{6n}{3n}}$

could some help me how to solve it, thanks

Comment: Have you tried using Stirling's approximation?

Comment: $$\color{red}{2}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{3^{3n}\cdot \left(\binom{2n}{n}\right)^2}{\binom{3n}{n}\cdot \binom{6n}{3n}}\right)
& = \lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{27^n\left(2n\right)!^3\left(3n\right)!}{n!^3\left(6n\right)!}\right)
\\& \approx \lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{27^n\left(\sqrt{2\pi \left(2n\right)}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}\right)^3\left(\sqrt{2\pi \left(3n\right)}\left(\frac{3n}{e}\right)^{3n}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{2\pi \left(n\right)}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\right)^3\left(\sqrt{2\pi \left(6n\right)}\left(\frac{6n}{e}\right)^{6n}\right)}\right)
\\& = \lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}\cdot \:\:3^{3n}\cdot \:\:8\sqrt{\pi \:}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{6n}\left(\frac{3n}{e}\right)^{3n}\left(n\pi \:\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\sqrt{3n}}{2^{\frac{5}{2}}\sqrt{3}\sqrt{n}\sqrt{\pi \:}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{3n}\left(\frac{6n}{e}\right)^{6n}\left(n\pi \:\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right)
\\& = \lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{3^{\frac{6n-1}{2}}\cdot \:\:8\left(\frac{3n}{e}\right)^{3n}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{6n}\sqrt{3n}}{2^2\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{3n}\left(\frac{6n}{e}\right)^{6n}}\right)
\\& = \lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{27^n\cdot \:\:3^{\frac{6n-1}{2}}\cdot \:\:2^{6n+3}\sqrt{3}n^{\frac{18n+1}{2}}e^{9n}}{e^{9n}\cdot \:\:729^n\cdot \:\:2^{6n+2}n^{\frac{18n+1}{2}}}\right)
\\& = \lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{2\cdot \:\:3^{\frac{6n-1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}\cdot \:\:3^{3n}}{3^{6n}}\right)
\\& = \color{red}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Solved with Stirling approximation 
$$x! \approx \sqrt{2\pi x}\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^x, \text{ for } x \to \infty$$

Answer (score 3):

Well, we have:

- $$\binom{2\cdot\text{n}}{\text{n}}=\frac{\left(2\cdot\text{n}\right)!}{\text{n}!\cdot\left(2\cdot\text{n}-\text{n}\right)!}=\frac{\left(2\cdot\text{n}\right)!}{\text{n}!\cdot\text{n}!}=\frac{\left(2\cdot\text{n}\right)!}{\left(\text{n}!\right)^2}\tag1$$
- $$\binom{3\cdot\text{n}}{\text{n}}=\frac{\left(3\cdot\text{n}\right)!}{\text{n}!\cdot\left(3\cdot\text{n}-\text{n}\right)!}=\frac{1}{\text{n}!}\cdot\frac{\left(3\cdot\text{n}\right)!}{\left(2\cdot\text{n}\right)!}\tag2$$
- $$\binom{6\cdot\text{n}}{3\cdot\text{n}}=\frac{\left(6\cdot\text{n}\right)!}{\left(3\cdot\text{n}\right)!\cdot\left(6\cdot\text{n}-3\cdot\text{n}\right)!}=\frac{\left(6\cdot\text{n}\right)!}{\left(\left(3\cdot\text{n}\right)!\right)^2}\tag3$$

So, we get:

$$\frac{\binom{2\cdot\text{n}}{\text{n}}^2}{\binom{3\cdot\text{n}}{\text{n}}\cdot\binom{6\cdot\text{n}}{3\cdot\text{n}}}=\frac{\left(\left(2\cdot\text{n}\right)!\right)^2}{\left(\text{n}!\right)^4}\cdot\frac{\text{n}!\cdot\left(2\cdot\text{n}\right)!\cdot\left(\left(3\cdot\text{n}\right)!\right)^2}{\left(3\cdot\text{n}\right)!\cdot\left(6\cdot\text{n}\right)!}=\frac{\left(\left(2\cdot\text{n}\right)!\right)^3}{\left(\text{n}!\right)^3}\cdot\frac{\left(3\cdot\text{n}\right)!}{\left(6\cdot\text{n}\right)!}\tag4$$

Comment: Right, but where does this even start to address the question?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Start simplifying $$\frac{3^{3 n} \binom{2 n}{n}^2}{\binom{3 n}{n} \binom{6 n}{3 n}}=\frac{27^n ((2 n)!)^3 (3 n)!}{(n!)^3 (6 n)!}$$ Take logarithms and use ,as user1337 commented, Stirling approximation of $\log(p!)$.

The problem becomes quite simple.

Comment: No need to use logs.